# Flutter not loading HomePage during first run, but loads properly with Hot Reload

Tags: flutter

I created a navigation menu with the home page as the starting item, but after editing my HomePage and running the app it only shows text with "Home Page" in the center. When I do Hot Reload, it works properly, but not on the first run (Also to note, this occurs only for iOS run, it works properly for Android)

**UPDATE:**  I changed the name of the application via Xcode. So, then in ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj find /* Debug */ = { section, and there change value of PRODUCT_NAME to Runner. After that use flutter clean && flutter run to run the app. It should fix the issue.

Comment: What is NavigationStates? How does main() looks like? Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I solved the issue and updated with the fix.